# General Rendezvous with Semaphores

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, semaphore

I'm working through the [The Little Book of Semaphores](http://www.greenteapress.com/semaphores/) on implementing a barrier for rendezvous.  Does the following code work as a barrier?

If we have the following variables:

```
n = the number of threads
barrier = Semaphore(-n + 1)
```

And we execute `n` threads on the following code.

```
# Rendezvous
barrier.signal()
barrier.wait()
barrier.signal()

# critical point
```

#### Book Answer

Here's the author's variables.

```
n = the number of threads
count = 0
mutex = Semaphore(1)
barrier = Semaphore(0)
```

Author's barrier solution

```
mutex.wait()
count = count + 1
mutex.signal()

if count == n: barrier.signal()

barrier.wait()
barrier.signal()

# critical point
```

I understand the author's solution, I want to know if my approach works.

Comment: Yes, your solutions looks completely correct, and actually is kind of ingenious.

Comment: Oh sweet, thanks. So, uh, what do I do with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your solution is that signal doesn't just open up the process if the value goes to 1, it will remove 1 process from the semaphore's queue even if the value is -100. So your first process arrives, it signals the barrier to go to -n+2, then waits to put it back at -n-1. The next one comes and signals, which releases the first, then causing it to signal again. Basically, your code will only stop the first n processes arriving until the next process arrives in sets of 2, not until all n arrive.

Furthermore, the correct answer allows for repetition as long as you reset count, whereas yours fails if the same processes come back for round 2.